# Get list from previous query that was a datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I need the branch & account number column from a previous query.

```
qry = (from row in iockmas.DataTable.AsEnumerable()
    where row[Schema_CreditCardFile.Fields.AutomaticBillYN.ToString()].ToString() == "Y"          
    select row);

var bracct = (from x in qry select new { x["Branch"].ToString(), x["Account"].ToString() }).ToArray();
```

When I do the last query, visual studio doesn't like the x["Account"] part:

[image]

How do I reference the Branch and Account column from the previous query?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, `x.[` is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 4):

The error message sounds like it's telling you to give the members of your anonymous type a name.

Try this:

```
var bracct = (from x in qry select new 
{ 
    Val1 = x["Branch"].ToString(), 
    Val2 = x["Account"].ToString() 
}).ToArray();
```